# Automapper on DataTable with spaces in column names

Tags: c#, datatable, automapper, idatareader

Say I have:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Data Guid", typeof(Guid));
dt.Rows.Add(10, "Jonesy", Guid.NewGuid());
```

I know I can map this to my custom class `Poco` using AutoMapper with:

```
public class Poco
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid DataGuid { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var pocos = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Poco>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

But, my column named `Data Guid` isn't mapped correctly as there is a space in the name.  Is there any way I can tell AutoMapper to remove spaces in column names before the mapping?

I've looked into a custom type converter and using the BeforeMap extension.  However I'm unable to alter the schema. Is this possible?

Just to cover all my bases, this is for a much larger project with the data coming from a source I cannot manipulate.

Comment: Which version of automapper are you using? DataReader support has been removed from core AutoMapper recently: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/33831e3b53ed1cd698558daa2db483906ec5c13a

Answer (score 1):

Define property map for your member like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataRecord, Poco>()
    .ForMember(x => x.DataGuid, o => o.MapFrom(
        s => s.GetGuid(s.GetOrdinal("Data Guid"))));
```

And then call Automapper like this:

```
var pocos = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Poco>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

`DynamicMap` is more for when you work with anonymous (dynamic) types.